# Any extrusions (including solidify modifier) only extrude faces in global y axis, rather than using normals

Tags: normals, extrude

I'm trying to create a shirt for a model by extruding some faces out a bit, but no matter how hard I try, the faces won't extrude properly. I've scoured the internet already, but haven't had any luck finding a solution. I'll add the download for the file if you want to see for yourself.

As you can see, the normals on my mesh are correct. There aren't any duplicate verts or faces.

[image: Normals]

But when applying any extrusion or solidify, the generated faces only scale out in the y axis.

[image: Normals Extruded]

Here's the link to download.

[Download Romy.blend from Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmku3k6t2pmxwlq/Romy.blend?dl=0)

Comment: please don't use dropbox to share .blend files, use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your post and paste the provided link. This free service will make your file permanent and embedded in the question text (works also for answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the scale of your object with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>. Then your *Solidify* will work correctly. If you choose to extrude instead, then use <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> afterwards, i.e. shrink scale.

Comment: I've been searching for hours. I can't believe the solution was this simple! Is there a reason the scale has to be applied?